# FAST REPORT VCL data band

Tags: delphi, report, delphi-2006, fastreport

Normally in fast report, the data band lines up rows vertically . Now
i want to design a report in which i should use a data band line up horizontally

Is there any way or techniques with this?

Comment: You should always **add** the generic [tag:delphi] tag to your delphi related questions to have the correct syntax highlighter and more attention on your question.

Comment: you mean a column based report? if is really that it then check the property "Column" from the "TfrxReportPage" or "TfrxMasterData"

Comment: no, the datas should in horizontal ex.
field EMP_NO.

output :

a b c d e f g h

usually data in fast reports output like this

a
b
c
d
in vertical form

Comment: @chaco i don't think that is possible. the only way to render content horizontally is by using the columns i said before.

Answer (score 0):

You may use vertical bands if you have FR Standart, FR Professional of FR Enterprise. Free FR Embarcadero edition doesn't have vertical bands support